# The best way to deploy COM classes from a .NET assembly on the user's computer

Tags: .net, com, installation, .net-assembly, regasm

I've written an assembly that registers and works fine on my development machine using regasm. I'm wondering what's the recommended way to deploy such a library on the users' computers. My users will use the COM library from Excel VBA.

I know I can write a simple script that calls regasm and deliver it to the users, but I'm not sure if it's the best practice. For example, after delivering a couple of updates, my users may end up with several versions of the library registered, so I'd like to offer them a way to uninstall an older version if not needed anymore. The users will write the VBA scripts on their own, so they'll know what version of the COM library they use, so they should be able to tell what versions can be uninstalled.

What's the best practice?

Comment: This cannot be meaningfully answered if you don't say anything at all about the kind of client programs that you expect to use this server.  COM has a strong DLL Hell problem, you *will* get into trouble by just arbitrary removing or replacing old versions.  The odds that you will break a client program are very high.

Comment: So you have no idea whatsoever what version the client programmers are using.  Do *not* automatically uninstall old versions, you have to leave it up to them.  Make sure that a new version can peacefully co-exist with an old one.  Which means you'll have to deploy to the GAC with a new [AssemblyVersion].  And follow the COM rules, changes in the interfaces requires new guids so the registration of a new version doesn't overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to install applications and it has support for creating these registration entries using a tool in it's suite called Heat.  It has a bit of a learning curve but I've found it to be an awesome installer suite.  It's free and it's widely used.

If your looking for a simpler solution you could just create a batch file like you say to register/unregister the dll(s) manually and to install/uninstall files.